# Retrieve data from database to view in laravel 8

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, database, laravel

Hi every one my problem is, I try to retrieve data from database and wanna show them on view but I get some problem because the data that I retrieved it from two tables the tables has one to one relationship when I retrieve the data it's very good without any problem but when I passed the data to view I want to show the data that is in the table that has the foreign key

[image: This my controller that retrieve the data from database and pass them to view]

[image: This the model of donarT table note that this the table that has the foreign key which is idRequest_FK column]

[image: This is the model of Request_donar table that has the one to one relation with donarT]

[image: Here is the view that I am trying to show the retrieved data on it]

[image: This is the result on my view look for this the data that are from donarT table is showed with any error but the last two columns that are content the data from Request_donar table are not showin this is my error]

Comment: Please add your code here as text. Code images are hard to read and extremely hard to troubleshoot.

Comment: As per the [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide, which you are encouraged to read before using the site, please don't post images of your code. Code is text. Pasting it as graphics is very impractical as it can't be copied, searched, re-used in answers etc. It makes it difficult for those who might want to help you. Please edit your question to include the code as text and use the [formatting tools](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to present it nicely, so that it is usable for those who want to help you. Thanks

Comment: You also didn't really explain your issue. "I want" isn't a question, or a description of a problem. What have you researched? What have you tried? Where exactly are you stuck? We are willing to help, but we usually like to see some evidence of your own attempts first.

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)